# How to collect user defined exit status of pthread

Tags: c, pthreads

How to collect and check the exit status of a thread when a thread is cancelled using `pthread_cancel`
Below program I am trying to check the status using `PTHREAD_CANCELED` and other user specified value.

For cancelled thread `if(status == PTHREAD_CANCELED)` is true , but for user specified exit value
`if(status == errNum)` is not true, it would be true if handle `if(status == *(int *)errNUM)` , but if I use same way to get to know the value of  `PTHREAD_CANCELED` using `*(int *)PTHREAD_CANCELED` it will be  a segfault, why so?

By the way one more question is it allowed to cancel a same thread from itself `pthread_cancel(pthread_self());`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *thread_func(void *arg);
void *thread_func2(void *arg);
int errNum = 3;
pthread_t st_id;

int main()
{
    pthread_t t_id, t_id2;
    void *status;

    // on success pthread_create return zero
    if(pthread_create(&t_id,NULL,thread_func,NULL) != 0){
        printf("thread creation failed\n");
        return 0;   
    }
    printf("thread created with id %u successfully\n",t_id);
    st_id = t_id;

    if(pthread_create(&t_id2,NULL,thread_func2,NULL) != 0){
        printf("thread creation failed\n");
        return 0;   
    }
    printf("thread created with id %u successfully\n",t_id2);

    if(pthread_join(t_id,&status) == 0){
        printf("join success \n");
        if(status == PTHREAD_CANCELED){
            printf("Thread %u cancelled successfully,value =%u\n",t_id,*(int *)status);
        }else if(status){
            printf("thread %u exited with status %u\n",t_id,status);
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("join failed \n");
    }

    if(pthread_join(t_id2,&status) == 0){
        printf("join success for tid2\n");
        if(status == PTHREAD_CANCELED){
            printf("Thread %u cancelled successfully, value = %u\n",t_id2,*(int *)status);
        }else if(status){
            printf("thread %u exited with status %u\n",t_id2,status);
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("join failed for tid2\n");
    }

    return 0;
}


void *thread_func(void *arg)
{
    printf("Inside thread_func :%u\n",pthread_self());
    sleep(3);
    pthread_exit(0);

}


void *thread_func2(void *arg)
{
    printf("Inside thread_func2 :%u\n",pthread_self());
    pthread_cancel(st_id);
    pthread_exit(&errNum);
}
```

Comment: `PTHREAD_CANCELED` *is* the exit status of a cancelled thread. And it's unlikely to be a valid address of an int, hence the segfault when you try treating it like one.

Comment: well, that's reasonable , but if I have to do the same for checking any user defined value `if(status == PTHREAD_USER_DEFINED_STATUS1)`, then how do we pass the status in `pthread_exit` and collect in `pthread_join`

Comment: A cancelled thread cannot pass an exit status to `pthread_join()`.  The thread was cancelled; it doesn't get to choose what value is passed to `pthread_join()`.

Comment: How and where is `errNum` defined?

Comment: updated...header and global

Comment: The posted code does not compile.  The compiler outputs many warning messages, several of which are very serious.  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same things